# How to access a file name containing URL encoding through the browser?

Tags: html, apache, browser

I created a file name called `"%20%20.txt"` and uploaded in my webs space.

When I am trying to access above file through URL by typing `"http://mysite/%20%20.txt"`, it is showing an error that the file is not found. I know that `"%20"` will be decoded as a blank space.

How is it possible to access the file through URL?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `%20` that you use in the URL will be decoded, so you are looking for the file `"  .txt"`, but the `%20` that you used to create the file is not decoded, so the actual name of the file is `"%20%20.txt"`.

You need to use the URL `http://mysite/%2520%2520.txt` to access the file `"%20%20.txt"`. The `%25` is the encoded form of `%`.

Answer (score 4):

Use `%2520%2520.txt`, `%25` decodes as the percent-sign `%`. You can use the table on http://www.asciitable.com/. The number after the percent-sign is a hexadecimal representation of the ASCII value.

If you have a long string, you could also use Javascript's `encodeURIComponent` function:

```
prompt("Encoded:", encodeURIComponent("%20%20.txt"))
```

This could be executed in the Javascript console (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>J</kbd> in Firefox) and displays a dialog containing the escape value.

Answer (score 2):

If your file name really is `%20%20.txt`, try http://yoursite.com/%2520%2520.txt.

%25 is the percentage encoded.

Answer (score 2):

You need to escape those percent signs:

```
http://mysite/%2520%2520.txt
```