# RewriteRule causing 403

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I restored a website from webarchive so it has files with file names like:

```
blog.html
blog.html%3fstart%3d10
blog.html%3fstart%3d20
blog.html%3fstart%3d30
```

And the pagination was working with links like blog.html?start=10 etc.

So I need simple redirect. My .htaccess looks like the following, but getting 403 error.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^start=([0-9]+)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /blog.html\%253fstart\%253d%1 [L]
```

But I am getting 500 error (looked in apache log that it was infinite internal redirect), here's full apache log:

```
strip per-dir prefix: F:/OSPanel/domains/test3/blog.html -> blog.html
applying pattern '^(.*)$' to uri 'blog.html'
rewrite 'blog.html' -> '/blog.html%253fstart%253d10'
trying to replace context docroot F:/OSPanel/domains/test3 with context prefix 
internal redirect with /blog.html%253fstart%253d10 [INTERNAL REDIRECT]
strip per-dir prefix: F:/OSPanel/domains/test3/blog.html%3fstart%3d10 -> blog.html%3fstart%3d10
applying pattern '^(.*)$' to uri 'blog.html%3fstart%3d10'
rewrite 'blog.html%3fstart%3d10' -> '/blog.html%253fstart%253d10'
trying to replace context docroot F:/OSPanel/domains/test3 with context prefix 
internal redirect with /blog.html%253fstart%253d10 [INTERNAL REDIRECT]
strip per-dir prefix: F:/OSPanel/domains/test3/blog.html%3fstart%3d10 -> blog.html%3fstart%3d10
applying pattern '^(.*)$' to uri 'blog.html%3fstart%3d10'
rewrite 'blog.html%3fstart%3d10' -> '/blog.html%253fstart%253d10'
trying to replace context docroot F:/OSPanel/domains/test3 with context prefix 
internal redirect with /blog.html%253fstart%253d10 [INTERNAL REDIRECT]
```

And the last block repeats 10 times
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: if you take out the second line?

Comment: It did not help.

Comment: Your RewriteRule is actually wrong. Try `RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}     ^start=([0-9]+)$`  `RewriteRule ^(.*)$  /blog.html\%3fstart\%3d%1`. It's not fully ok but may work.

Comment: Thanks for attempt but still the same: "You don't have permission to access /blog.html?start=10 on this server. Additionally, a 403 Forbidden error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request." Even though I added ErrorDocument processing in .htaccess file.

Comment: file/server permissions? Now it looks like the apache user really don't have right permissions.

Comment: I am using OpenServer on windows. As far as I know it has full rights. How do I check this for sure? Also tried to upload this site on my server as it is and got 500 error.

Comment: try the site without htaccess at all - there is "blog.html" without percents, or just make some test html file. If it works, then it is smth wrong with htaccess, if not  - it is another problem (not to do with this post).

Comment: Ok. I have only blog.html, blog.html%3dstart%3f10 now in folder and still getting 403.

Comment: that is, there is no .htaccess and you write `http://blabla.com/blog.html` in browser?

Comment: When I write blabla.com/blog.html or blabla.com/blog.html?start=10, I am getting the page correctly. But if I am typing blabla.com/blog.html%3fstart%3d10 I am getting 403

Comment: read this [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11070499/how-to-access-a-file-name-containing-url-encoding-through-the-browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11070499/how-to-access-a-file-name-containing-url-encoding-through-the-browser)

Comment: Ok, got it. Now I have RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /blog.html\%253fstart\%253d%1. But now it's 500 error

Comment: So, you get correctly blabla.com/blog.html and blabla.com/blog.html?start=10, and  blabla.com/blog.html%25%3fstart%25%3d10. What is your goal now? what do you want to rewrite to get what?

Comment: When user trying to access blog.html?start=10, I need it to fetch the file with file name blog.html%3fstart%3d10. So I guess it must rewrite blog.html?start=10 to blog.html%253fstart%253d10. Which I was trying to do(comment above)

Comment: `RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^start=([0-9]+)$`  
`RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /blog.html\%25%3fstart\%25%3d%1` like previously - it's not fully ok, but may work

Comment: Yes, that's what I tried, but without unslashed % like you did. But I am getting 500 error. It's like apache does not like % symbol in url at all. Your version giving 500 too

Comment: How about fixing the file names, is this no option?

Comment: there is a redundant '%' before '3' (twice) in my previous comment

Comment: Fixing file names does not seem like solution to me. See, I have to restore many web sites. So I'll have to change file names AND links to them in all pages. That looks harder than properly adjust .htacces just once :D

Comment: It looks like it's not going to work - you cannot redirect to a filename with a % in it.

Comment: Actually, it sounds very strange with these filenames. Are there really files in directory? Are they necessary? That is, you need blog.html but all the other with "%3fstart%3d10" are not used? Because this string means only a parameter string to blog.html.

Comment: Yes, there are actually files wiht these file names. Yes, they are parameters, but that's how parameters looks when you need convert php version to html in some tool, I am using to restore dropped websites.